# JasperException: absolute uri cannot be resolved in aem 6.4

Tags: jsp, uri, aem, meta-inf

Using IntelliJ
Inside my project, i have this path bundle/src/main/resources/META-INF/cet-tags.tld

cet-tags.tld is:

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <tlib-version>3.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>cet</short-name>
    <uri>http://www.sample.com/sample/taglib</uri>
    <tag>
</tag>
```

when i open a page, the page shows a jasper exception:
JasperException: page.jsp(4,0) The absolute uri: http://www.sample.com/sample/taglib cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application